# Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x00007FF667D911C8 в 6.1.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x000000B5039192D8

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Мне нужно выписать слова со строки, которые начинаются и заканчиваются с цифры, например 4слово4. Я новичок, и я не понимаю почему мне выдает такую ошибку при компиляции :Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x00007FF667D911C8 в 6.1.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x000000B5039192D8. Помогите пожалуйста исправить ошибки
Код :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    char word[] = "слово слово 4ов4 слово 6тттттттт6 слово";

     int s = strlen(word);
     int* f = new int[s];
     int* l = new int[s];

     for(int i = 0; i < s; i++ ) cout << word[i];
     cout << "\n\n";
     int n = 0;

     for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
     {
         if (word[i] == ' ' && isdigit(word[i + 1]) != 0)
         {
             f[i] = i+1;
             n++;
         }
         if (isdigit(word[i]) != 0 && word[i + 1] == ' ')
         {
             l[i] = i;
             n++;
         }
     } 
    char **W = new char*[n/2];
    for (int i = 0; i < n/2; i++) W[i] = new char[20];
    for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++)
    {
        int a = f[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        {

            W[i][j] = word[j + f[i]];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        {
            cout << W[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Очередной раз путают компиляцию и выполнение программы...

Comment: Вам надо именно руками весь разбор строки? Так нельзя? `char word[] = "слово слово 4ов4 слово 6тттттттт6 слово";
    istringstream in(word);
    string s;
    while(in>>s) if (isdigit(s[0])) cout << s << endl;`

Comment: Я просто настолько новичек, что даже не знаю что это : in>>s означает( .Поэтому  я делаю таким способом. Спасибо за ответ

Comment: мне хотелось бы узнать как пофиксить то что есть

Answer (score 0):

Я уже понял, на самом деле у меня первые элементы масивов f и l были пустыми, а я хотел их использовать в цыкле, в конце програмы